# SAS Web Report Studio - how to count distinct values in crosstabs

Tags: count, aggregate, sas

In SAS Web Report Studio 3.1 I need to count distinct occurences for selected dimensions and display the results in a crosstable.
According to the SAS Support Web site this aggregate function is not supported in cross tablulations, but maybe there is a work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Just create a new measure variable in info map. The expression for making this variable shall look like 
N ( Distinct <>)
While creating WRS just drag and drop this field along with the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Web Report Studio just does not support "count distinct measures". I was at a SAS conference where they demo'ed 4.2 (?) that's included with the SAS 9.2 suite and that didn't appear to have any substantial functionality either. Just a bunch of interface improvements.

At my company we used a 3rd party product Futrix that sits on top of SAS and basically is a much more advanced version of Web report studio. It has count distinct measures built in. Basically, in terms of functionality Futrix is light years ahead of SAS Web Report Studio. Of course, it is not a free software, so I don't know how much this will help.

Bottom-line: Don't look to SAS Web Report studio if you want to implement any kind of serious web-based reporting.

Answer (score 0):

To add a distinct count you need to create a new measure in the cube related to an available hierarchy.

Keep in mind that when you drill up and down the sum of the drill down will be greater than the sum of the level below.  This correctly follows the definition of distinct, but is commonly misunderstood.

The first two answers to this question are wrong please ignore them.